# SharePoint Framework – Loading Font Awesome CSS from CDN

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-tooling

I am fairly new to the SharePoint Framework development stack (TS, React, node, etc.) and am looking to incorporate the font-awesome suite into my web-part via a CDN.

Normally I would reference this in an HTML header:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

How do I go about doing this? I've seen a few examples on GitHub with external javascript libraries but nothing CSS/font driven like this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way to load CSS from CDN is using the ModuleLoader class.

First you import ModuleLoader in your code:

```
import ModuleLoader from '@microsoft/sp-module-loader';
```

Then, in the web part's constructor you use it to load the CSS file from CDN:

```
public constructor(context: IWebPartContext) {
  super(context);

  ModuleLoader.loadCss('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css');
}
```

Answer (score 8):

In SPFX GA version the ModuleLoader was renamed to SPComponentLoader.

```
import { SPComponentLoader } from `'@microsoft/sp-loader';
```

It continues to be userd in constructor:

```
constructor() {
    super();

    SPComponentLoader.loadCss('...');
}
```

Please check the [reference reply](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/364):